# Why does smiling indicate happiness? Why couldn’t frowning indicate happiness and smiling indicate sadness?

Tags: social-psychology, behavior, behaviorism, evolution, evolutionary-psychology

Is there an evolutionary reason behind this? What about raising eyebrows when surprised, or lowering them when angry?